# PowerBI measure calculates average incorrectly - why?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

To preface this, I'm fairly experienced in Excel and VBA but new to PowerBI and more than a bit confused.

I have a flat table with a [creationdate]-, [Prio] (Priority (1,2,3)) and a calculated [Days Open] column, among many irrelevant others. I need to create a chart that displays the average days a case was open by priority of the case.

To display the average "days required" per (opening-) month for the past 18 months, I created the following measure:

```
Prio 1 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('SourceName'[Days Open]),'SourceName'[Prio]=1)
```

Then I used that as a value, and used the [creationdate] as the x-axis. (Later I changed the x-axis to a new date table linked to [creationdate] without it making a difference.) To display this as monthly averages, I used the hierarchy limited to years and months, and went down one level in the chart.

Something seemed off so I checked first in Excel, then in the data source in PowerBI and yep: The averages in the PowerBI chart are complete bullshit.

Where did I go wrong? I assume it has something to do with the date hierarchy... So I created a date table as recommended (which....why?!) and linked it. That didn't make a difference.

Meanwhile in the data panel if I filter by the date column and calculate the average with the filtered selection of numbers externally, everything works as expected, so its not like there's a date formatting issue.

Do I have to create a calculated column with something akin to

```
DATE(YEAR([DateColumn]),MONTH([DateColumn]),1)
```

, then use that as the x-axis without the hierarchy, and hope nobody cares about the day in the label? Or is there something wrong with the measure used? I'm completely lost.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without seeing what your data table looks like, what you are currently getting, and what you expect to see.

Comment: The info in the table is confidential, but I mean, it's a table. It has columns and rows. One column has the reference dates, one has the numbers to be averaged. I expect the correct averages displayed in the chart (averages per month per priority) and get wrong ones, usually between 1 and 50% off the mark.

I've been fighting PowerBI for two days now over something that takes me 5 minutes to calculate and present in Excel.

Comment: You never need to share confidential information but if you can't provide a representative example for someone to reproduce your issue then you aren't likely to get a useful answer. I'm not sure it's even possible to diagnose your issue with the limited information you've shared so far.

Comment: To be very honest I have no idea what to share between describing the table and just sharing the table itself.

But I take this to mean that the measure would have been correct and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Not what I was suggesting at all. Power BI can do averages just fine but you have to know how to write the DAX for your particular situation. It's very likely that you aren't understanding the filter context for the measure correctly and thus your measure is returning an answer to a different question than you intend. Nobody can help you fix that if you don't provide enough information to work with though. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example